# Spring / Glassfish 3.1.2 stale files

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm currently developping an application using Spring Web MVC & Spring Security.

I can deploy it on Glassfish 3.1.2 but when I want to redeploy after some bug fixing, I get this error :

```
WARNING: Exception while locating sub archive: XXX.war
WARNING: DPL8031: Ignoring XXX_war/ because the containing archive C:\dev\apps\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\XXX recorded it as a pre-existing stale file
```

.glassfishStaleFiles contains :

```
XXX_war/
XXX_war/WEB-INF/
XXX_war/WEB-INF/lib/
XXX_war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
```

And indeed, spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar still exists and when I try to remove it, I get a message that says It's still in use by JVM.

I found this link :
https://www.java.net//forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/stale-files-when-undeploying-web-app-glassfish-3

My question is : does someone have a workaround for this issue ?

It's really annoying while developping...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after some days of research...

I finally found how to get around.

My project hierarchy was :

```
XXX.ear
--- lib/
------ XXX_Entities.jar
--- XXX_Ejb.jar
--- XXX_EjbClient.jar
--- XXX_Web.war
------ WEB-INF/lib/
--------- *libraries*
```

Now :

```
XXX.ear
--- lib/
------ XXX_Entities.jar
------ *libraries*
--- XXX_Ejb.jar
--- XXX_EjbClient.jar
--- XXX_Web.war
```

Then add lib folder to EAR deployment assembly and it **works**. Glassfish unload correctly when undeploying.

Answer (score 8):

To correct this problem, I have an easier solution : 
Assuming your EAR file is correct:

1. stop the server
2. goto your EAR directory :
   C:\java_apps\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\XXX_EAR
3. delete the file called .glassfishStaleFiles
4. restart server and re-deploy EAR file

It did the trick for me.

Comment: Actually, sometimes there is only this file `.glassfishStaleFiles` but sometimes a lib in a child folder is still considered as loaded and can't be removed. Indeed, stop/remove/restart works but it takes more time than my solution.

Comment: this helped me alot.