# Include libraries in EAR with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'd like to use maven to include jar/war's libraries in my EAR project's lib folder.

Currently my ear looks like this :

```
lib
lib/<entities>.jar
lib/<ejb-client>.jar
<ejb-impl>.jar
<web-app-project>.war
```

Each jar/war have maven dependencies which are declared with scope provided.

Why scope provided? I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2 and having issue when I put libraries in `/WEB-INF/lib`. I fixed the issue by copying libs in ear/lib instead (see [Spring / Glassfish 3.1.2 stale files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479553/spring-glassfish-3-1-2-stale-files)).

What I want to do is to tell to maven he has to put thoses librairies in the ear's lib folder.

I tried to put all projects in the ear's maven dependencies but it's not working actually.

Could someone help me ?

Thanks,

Smoky

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is similar to [Including A Third Party Library In application.xml](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/including-a-third-party-library-in-application-xml.html)

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
           [...]
           <modules>
             <jarModule>
               <groupId>artifactGroupId</groupId>
               <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
               <bundleFileName>entities.jar</bundleFileName>
             </jarModule>
          </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I'll have to define all dependencies in the `<modules>` nodes? There's nothing to do this automatically?

Comment: yes, this is required. For thanks upvote and accept my answer :)